# Python Pandas GroupBy to plot a line chart and bar chart side by side (in 1 image)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, charts

A dataframe of different columns that I want to plot them (from GroupBy) into a line chart and bar chart side by side (in 1 image).

With below lines that produces 2 separate charts, I tried but still not able to get them into a side-side-side 1 image.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO(
"""
Name    Year - Month    Score   Thumbs-up
Mike    2022-09 192 5
Mike    2022-08 708 5
Mike    2022-07 140 3
Mike    2022-05 144 8
Mike    2022-04 60  10
Mike    2022-03 108 4
Kate    2022-07 19850   5
Kate    2022-06 19105   2
Kate    2022-05 23740   3
Kate    2022-04 19780   9
Kate    2022-03 15495   4 """)

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

for group_name, sub_frame in df.groupby("Name"):

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))"

    sub_frame_sorted = sub_frame.sort_values('Year - Month')       # sort the data-frame by a column"

    line_chart = sub_frame_sorted.plot(""Year - Month"", ""Score"", legend=False)"
    bar_chart = sub_frame_sorted.plot.bar(""Year - Month"", ""Thumbs-up"", legend=False)"

    # for data labeling in the charts
    i=0
    for ix, vl in sub_frame_sorted.iterrows():
        line_chart.annotate(vl['Score'], (i, vl['Score']), ha='center')
        bar_chart.annotate(vl['Thumbs-up'], (i, vl['Thumbs-up']), ha='center')
        i=i+1

    plt.show()
```

What's the right way to do so (if matplotlib can do so)?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, matplotlib can do this. Now, I had to modify your csv input a little to do it and I think you should format your data before using the method, but you are looking for a way to plot so I hope you don't disagree with the formatting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO(
"""
Name;Year-Month;Score;Thumbs-up
Mike;2022-09;192;5
Mike;2022-08;708;5
Mike;2022-07;140;3
Mike;2022-05;144;8
Mike;2022-04;60;10
Mike;2022-03;108;4
Kate;2022-07;19850;5
Kate;2022-06;19105;2
Kate;2022-05;23740;3
Kate;2022-04;19780;9
Kate;2022-03;15495;4 """)

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = ';', engine='python')
print(df)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))

for group_name, sub_frame in df.groupby("Name"):

    sub_frame_sorted = sub_frame.sort_values('Year-Month')       # sort the data-frame by a column"

    sub_frame_sorted.plot(ax=axes[0], x="Year-Month", y="Score", label=group_name)
    sub_frame_sorted.plot(ax=axes[1], kind='bar', x="Year-Month", y="Thumbs-up", label=group_name)

    for i, (ix, vl) in enumerate(sub_frame_sorted.iterrows()):
        axes[0].annotate(vl['Score'], (i, vl['Score']), ha='center')
        axes[1].annotate(vl['Thumbs-up'], (i, vl['Thumbs-up']), ha='center')

axes[0].set_xlabel('Year-Month')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Score')
axes[0].legend()

axes[1].set_xlabel('Year-Month')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Thumbs-up')
axes[1].legend()

plt.show()
```

will return:
[image]

**EDIT**  Another alternative is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO(
"""
Name;Year-Month;Score;Thumbs-up
Mike;2022-09;192;5
Mike;2022-08;708;5
Mike;2022-07;140;3
Mike;2022-05;144;8
Mike;2022-04;60;10
Mike;2022-03;108;4
Kate;2022-07;19850;5
Kate;2022-06;19105;2
Kate;2022-05;23740;3
Kate;2022-04;19780;9
Kate;2022-03;15495;4 """)

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = ';', engine='python')
print(df)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))

for group_name, sub_frame in df.groupby("Name"):

    sub_frame_sorted = sub_frame.sort_values('Year-Month')       # sort the data-frame by a column"

    sub_frame_sorted.plot(ax=axes[0], x="Year-Month", y="Score", label=group_name)
    sub_frame_sorted.plot(ax=axes[1], kind='bar', x="Year-Month", y="Thumbs-up", label=group_name)

    xticks = sub_frame_sorted["Year-Month"][::2].tolist()  # only include every other x-axis label
    for i, (ix, vl) in enumerate(sub_frame_sorted.iterrows()):
        axes[0].annotate(vl['Score'], (i, vl['Score']), ha='center')
        axes[1].annotate(vl['Thumbs-up'], (i, vl['Thumbs-up']), ha='center')

    axes[0].set_xticks(sub_frame_sorted.index[::2])
    axes[0].set_xticklabels(xticks, rotation=45)
    axes[1].set_xticks(sub_frame_sorted.index[::2])
    axes[1].set_xticklabels(xticks, rotation=45)

axes[0].set_xlabel('Year-Month')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Score')
axes[0].legend()

axes[1].set_xlabel('Year-Month')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Thumbs-up')
axes[1].legend()

plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: can you please also show how to limit the number of ticks in x-axis too? I've tried added the "x_compat=True" to the ".plot" line but it doesn't work.

Comment: much grateful to the update! When I loop and try to Kate's and Mike's as separate pairs, the second pair (Kate's line and bar charts' x-asis get push rightwards (no ticks on x-axis on the left). Can you please help again? Thanks!